# Rails is overloading path definition inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project and a `gems` folder in this project, where I have a gem called `ip_locator`. I then have a class like this:

```
require 'singleton'
require 'maxminddb'

module IpLocator
  class Service
    include Singleton

    attr_reader :db

    def initialize
      @db = ::MaxMindDB.new('db/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb')
    end

    def locate(ip)
      db.lookup ip
    end
  end
end
```

I have some rspec tests for this class inside the gem folder as well. they run fine. Also, if I run `./gems/ip_locator/bin/console` I can interact with this class fine.
But when I try to run this class from Rails's context (going to root folder and `rails console`) I get this:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - db/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb
```

I copied this file to my ROOT/db instead ROOT/gems/ip_locator/db and it worked so I noticed that Rails is actually expecting that this path (`db/GeoIp2`) is relative to the project root, it is not loading from the gem. How do I deal with it?

Comment: What if you do `::MaxMindDB.new(Rails.root.join('db', 'GeoIP2-Country.mmdb'))`

Comment: the gem does not depend on Rails...and I wan't to be able to run their tests without Rails of course

Comment: ok, then you need to pass this path as configuration or in constructor